# How to set multiple id with ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android

Here is my declared ArrayAdapter :

```
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.activity_task,
            R.id.taskTitle,
            items1);
```

I wanted to do that :

```
itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.activity_task,
            R.id.taskTitle,
            items1,
            R.id.taskNews,
            items2);
```

Because, my app is like :

- Task 1
- Task 2

And, I'm trying to do :

- Task 1
- Task's description 1
- Task 2
- Task's description 2

How it's possible to add multiple id ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using list view to show the text items, then you can only use one layout and one text view using standard ArrayAdapter.

To use two TextView's try making a CustomListAdapter

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166802/7514132) link for reference on [CustomListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166802/7514132)